# jqGrid is failing to loading data

Tags: javascript, c#, jqgrid

Hi i got a simple actinReault which return jsonResult. The method  is following.

```
[HttpPost]
    public  JsonResult AllEmployees()
    {
        EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
        List<EmployeeViewModel> employeesViewMod = employeeService.allEmployee();
        var AllEmpObjects= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeesViewMod); 
        return Json(AllEmpObjects);
    }
```

we can debug and see data on AllEmpObjects which is coming form DB

> "[{\"FirstName\":\"shuvo\",\"LastName\":\"ahmed\",\"Address1\":\"110, uttra\",\"Address2\":\"mymansing\",\"HomePhone\":1234,\"MobileNo\":2345,\"Email\":\"suvo@yahoo.com\",\"Dob\":\"10/01/1977\",\"StartDate\":\"2013-10-01T00:00:00\",\"InitialSalary\":0,\"AccHolderName\":null,\"BankName\":\"brac\",\"Brunch\":\"uttra\",\"AccountNo\":1234567890,\"PositionDDLId\":0,\"MarriageStatDDLId\":0,\"PositionIdString\":\"Md\",\"MarriageIdString\":\"Married\"}]

My JS file which is responsible to show data using jqGrid:

```
function allEmployeeFunc() {
  $("#list").jqGrid({

          url: "/Employee/AllEmployees",
          datatype: "json",
          mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ["First name", "Last Name", "phone", "Mobile", "Email", "status"],

        colModel: [
        { name: "FirstName", width: 55 },
        { name: "LastName", width: 90 },
        { name: "HomePhone", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "MobileNo", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "Email", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "MarriageIdString", width: 150, sortable: false }
    ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "invid",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Detail of all EMPLOYEE",
});
```

}

unfortunately there is no data on output but the grid appears with empty inside. can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the line

```
var AllEmpObjects= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeesViewMod);
```

from your code and replace `return Json(AllEmpObjects);` to

```
return Json(employeesViewMod);
```

Comment: Dear @Oleg thanks a lot mate. job done. could you explain why i dont need to serialize here. without json conversion how i wrote "return Json(employeesViewMod);". yet employeesViewMod is not json converted yet.  normally when i receive data through AJAX i convert data/object to jason first in controller and json.parse to JS file and use the data/object. thanks again for being helpful.

Comment: @Cloud: You are welcome! `return Json(employeesViewMod);` already convert object to string having JSON format. The problem is that one can convert to JSON non-object types too: integers, boolean and strings. If you convert string to JSON then all `"` and `\` will be escaped (see [here](http://www.json.org/)). So you get the string `[{\"FirstName\":\"shuvo\",...}]` instead of the string `[{"FirstName":"shuvo",...}]`. Then on the client side the string will be deserialized to **the string** instead of to **object**. So jqGrid can't read the data because it expect the object (array of items).